# Refactoring chained RxJs subscriptions

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a piece of code that I need to refactor because it's a hell of chained subscriptions.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dossierService.getIdTree()
        .subscribe(idTree => {
            this.bootstrappingService.refreshObligations(idTree)
                .subscribe(() => {
                    this.dossierPersonsService.retrieveDossierPersons(idTree)
                        .subscribe(debtors => {
                            this.retrieveObligations();
                            this.debtors = debtors;
                        });
                });
        });
}
```

1. The first call `dossierService.getIdTree()` retrieves `idTree` which is used by other services except `obligationsService.retrieveObligations()`.
2. All service methods should be executed in the order they executed now. But `retrieveDossierPersons` and `retrieveObligations` can be executed in parallel.
3. `retrieveObligations()` is a method that subscribes to another observable. This method is used in a few other methods.

I've refactored it and it seems to work. But did I refactor it in a proper way or my code can be improved?

```
   this.dossierService.getIdTree()
      .pipe(
        map(idTree => {
          this.idTree = idTree;
        }),
        switchMap(() => {
          return this.bootstrappingService.refreshObligations(this.idTree)
        }),
        switchMap(
          () => {
            return this.dossierPersonsService.retrieveDossierPersons(this.idTree)
          },
        )
      )
      .subscribe(debtors => {
        this.retrieveObligations();
        this.debtors = debtors;
      });
```

Comment: I am not a big fan of this usage of `map` - it is acting as a side effect here. Did you mean `tap` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (not syntax checked):

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dossierService.getIdTree().pipe(
      switchMap(idTree =>
        this.bootstrappingService.refreshObligations(idTree)).pipe(
          switchMap(() => this.dossierPersonsService.retrieveDossierPersons(idTree).pipe(
            tap(debtors => this.debtors = debtors)
          )),
          switchMap(() => this.retrieveObligations())
        )
    ).subscribe();
  }
```

Using a higher-order mapping operator (`switchMap` in this case) will ensure that the inner observables are subscribed and unsubscribed.

In this example, you don't need to separately store idTree because you have access to it down the chained pipes.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
   const getIdTree$ = () => this.dossierService.getIdTree();
   const getObligations = idTree => this.bootstrappingService.refreshObligations(idTree);
   const getDossierPersons = idTree => this.dossierPersonsService.retrieveDossierPersons(idTree);

   getIdTree$().pipe(
     switchMap(idTree => forkJoin({
       obligations: getObligations(idTree)
       debtors: getDossierPersons(idTree),
     }))
   ).subscribe(({obligations, debtors}) => {
     // this.retrieveObligations(); // seems like duplicate of refreshObligations?
     this.debtors = debtors;
   });
 }
```

Depending on the rest of the code and on the template, you might also want to avoid unwrapping `debtors` by employing the `async` pipe instead

`forkJoin` will only complete when all of its streams have completed.
You might want also want to employ some error handling by piping `catchError` to each inner observable.

Instead of `forkJoin` you might want to use `mergeMap` or `concatMap` (they take an array rather than an object) - this depends a lot on logic and the UI. `concatMap` will preserve the sequence, `mergeMap` will not - in both cases, data could be display accumulatively, as it arrives. With `forkJoin` when one request gets stuck, the whole stream will get stuck, so you won't be able to display anything until all streams have completed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **switchMap** or the best choice is  **concatMap** to ensure orders of executions

```
obs1$.pipe(
 switchMap(data1 => obs2$.pipe(
   switchMap(data2 => obs3$)
 )
)
```